# How to convert a character taken from a string to an int?

Tags: c++, char, digits

So i have a string containing numbers, and i want to take one of those numbers and convert it to an int like that :

```
string s = "13245";
int a = stoi(s.at(3));
```

I have tried stoi :

```
int a = stoi(s.at(3));
```

I have tried atoi :

```
int a = atoi(s.at(3));
```

But none of those ways works, the only way i've found is the C way :

```
int a = s.at(3)-'0';
```

Do you know why stoi / atoi don't work ? Do you have any other way to convert a character taken from a string to an int ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

atoi accepts a const char*, whereas s.at(index) returns a char, hence the compiler will return a type error, rather you can do the following:

```
    string s = "13245";
    auto c = s.at(3);
    int a = atoi(&c);
```

Comment: For [`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), the argument is a *null-terminated* string, so you would have to do `char c[] = { s.at(3), 0 };` `int a = atoi(c);` (But at that point, you should do `s.at(3) - '0'`)

Comment: @lairv `atoi()` requires a null terminated string which `c` is not. Using the address of a single `char` is obviously wrong so this code doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

The function `stoi` expects an object of the type std::string. The C function `atoi` expects an object of the type `char *` that points to a string. While you are dealing with an object of the type char.

This

```
int a = s.at(3)-'0';
```

is the common approach to convert the internal representation of a digit character to the corresponding integer value because the codes of digits follow each other without gaps.

From the C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets)

> 3. ... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>      each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>      one greater than the value of the previous.

Comment: Oh ok and so isn't there a way to convert char to int other than c - '0' ?

Comment: @lairv Why do you need some other way?

Comment: C++ guarantees that it works as long as `c` contains a digit.

Comment: @lairv No, it is as I said a common approach.

Comment: Another way is to make a string of characters in alphabetical order and find the index. Or use a map of char to int.

Answer (score 1):

std::string is an array of chars and .at(3) or [3] will return you single char.
stoi and atoi work on strings (many chars) and will convert string like "-42" to its number representation -42.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    const std::string str = "1324509";

    for(const char ch: str) {
        const int a = ch & 0x0f; // the same as  ch - '0';
        printf("%i,",a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bb32e8a3c810e84)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

*Stoi* parses str interpreting its content as an integral number of the specified base and returned an int value.

```
int stoi (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

Parallel to your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo> 

using namespace std;

string s = "13245";
cout << typeid(s.at(3)).name();
// Prints out 'c' which means 'char'
```

So you need to convert *char* to *string* before using *stoi*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std

string s = "13245";
string m(1,s.at(3));
int a = stoi(m);
```